# How does mathematica deal with E^(- i t) (Euler formula)?

Tags: complex

I am trying to plot a function of time using Euler's formula for the temporal part. As we all know, exponentials with imaginary arguments are linked to `Cos` and `Sin` by Euler's formula. When plotting with `Manipulate` I only get a result at t=0, which makes sense because I guess Mathematica can compute it in 0 giving 1. While computing that exponential in other times, it probably doesn't plot anything because it doesn't know which part of Euler's formula I'm asking for. Is it not automatic for Mathematica to pick one between `Sin` and `Cos`? Not even if I tell Mathematica `ExpToTrig[Exp[- I omega t]] [[1]]` or [[2]] I get a result. So do I always have to state which part to take from the relationship given by Euler? And how? If we use `Re[Exp[- I omega t]]` it actually works. But why doesnt `ExpToTrig`?

```
 axisFlip = # /. {x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
  MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1], 
 x : (PlotRange -> _) :> x~Reverse~2} &;
 h = 5*10^-6;
 f = 173*10^3;
 omega = 2*N[Pi, 5]*f;
 Lc = Lnum/h;
 B1 = 1.8751;
 Lnum = N[250*10^-6];
 c = (Cos[B1 ] + Cosh[B1 ])/(Sin[B1  ] + Sinh[B1  ]);
 W[x_] = Cos[B1*x*h] - Cosh[B1*x*h] - c*(Sin[B1*x*h] - Sinh[B1*x*h]);
 dW[x1_] = -c (B1*h Cos[B1 x1 h] - B1*h Cosh[B1 x1 h]) - 
 B1*h Sin[B1 x1 h] - B1*h Sinh[B1 x1 h];
 vxbeam[x_, z_] = - I omega (- z dW[x]);
 vzbeam[x_] = -I omega (W[x ]);
 Manipulate[
 Plot[{Exp[- I omega t] Abs[vzbeam[x]], 
 Exp[- I omega t] Im[vzbeam[x]]}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Beam uniform z-component of velocity",
 AxesLabel -> {"m/s", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 1/2}, {-Abs[vzbeam[Lnum/h]], 
  Abs[vzbeam[Lnum/h]]}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5] // 
 axisFlip, {x, 0, Lnum/h, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {t, 0, 5/f, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: `Trig` doesn't mean real and so complex doesn't automatically make sense for plotting in Mathematica. You want a real part, take it. Was that the question?

Comment: @Kuba yes, but I was wondering: why if I take the first part of `ExpToTrig[Exp[- I omega t]]` isn't that equivalent to `Re`? As an output of `ExpToTrig[Exp[- I omega t]][[1]]` I get in fact `Cos[1.0870*10^6 t]` but `Plot` doesn't work

Comment: You can't count on `Part` for mathematical formulas. Take a look at `FullForm` of an expression. It will extrac the first element from the top expression but that does not mean anything in math context.

Comment: `ExpToTrig` essentially means: please eliminate all the `Exp[ I theta ]` in favor of `Cos[theta] + I Sin[theta]`.  That is, it's a function which coaxes Mathematica to adjust its [re]presentation of a quantity, rather than to actually change the quantity.  "Why" it isn't equivalent to `Re` is simply: it's not designed to accomplish that but to fill another niche.

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but Exp[-I omega t] Abs[vzbeam[x]] is a function of x and t but the Plot variable is given as {z, -1/2, 1/2}. How is this supposed to work ?